# How would you set getElementById when retrieving data from a different angular component?

Tags: html, angular, getelementbyid

I am working in Angular 6. I am trying to basically print a JS variable. The trouble is that the variable is created in one component but I am trying to print it in another.

What I did was create a service that would share that varaible with the new component. I then try to use `getElementById` to set the html id.

My more-information.html looks like:

```
<br>
<div>
   <div>
      <h2>User <span id="user"></span></h2>

</div>
```

I have a results component that does this:

```
this._informationServ.saveData(userArray);
this._informationServ.saveUser(user);
```

My information service does this:

```
export class InformationService {
  ourUser: string;
  userData = [];
  constructor() { }

saveUser(user){
  this.ourUser = user;
}

saveData(someArray){
  this.userData = someArray;
}

getUser(){
  return this.ourUser;
}

getData(){
  return this.userData;
}
}
```

And then finally I have a MoreInformation componenent that looks like:

```
export class MoreInformationComponent {
  finalData = [];
  ourUser: string;
  constructor(private _informationServ: InformationService) {  
    this.finalData = this._informationServ.getData();
    this.ourUser = this._informationServ.getUser();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I have tried using the line

```
document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = this.ourUser;
```

in the constructor of the MoreInformation Comp., which gave me the error:

```
TypeError: Unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference
```

I then tried creating a function `onCall()` inside the MoreInformation Comp. that does the `getElementbyId` line and call it in the constructor, which also did not work.

I also just tried doing something like

```
<br>
<div>
   <div>
      <h2>User {{ourUSer}}</h2>

</div>
```

But only User showed up
Would anyone have an idea on how to best do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to do it this way... I mean, it's not really "angularish".

Comment: I followed another answer I think on here and this is how they suggested. What would be a more angularish way to accomplish this? I am open to suggestions. I am new to angular so not sure on the best methods

Comment: Mate just add this here --> ```<h2>User <span id="user">{{ ourUser }}</span></h2>``` String interpolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the value like this:

```
document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = this.ourUser;
```

You can declare a variable in the component where you want to render the value and set it to this.ourUser value:

```
yourVariable = this.ourUser;
```

And then use it to show the value in your template:

```
<h2>User <span id="user">{{ yourVariable }}</span></h2>
```